# Prove/disprove the set of positive reals is a field under a different definition of addition and multiplication.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, logarithms

Define addition and multiplication as

$a \oplus b = ab \text{ and } a \otimes b = a^{\log{b}}.$

Given that the set is commutative since $a^{\log{b}}=b^{\log{a}},$ is it a field?
I have found that the identity element is 10 since $a \otimes 10 = a^{\log{10}} = a,$ but I can't find a solution $x$ in the positive reals for the equation $a \otimes x = 10.$

I'm just beginning Abstract Algebra so my foundation is the subject of rings is still shaky. Sorry if I've made any obvious mistakes.

Comment: Note that $1 \otimes x = 1$ for any $x$, so $a \otimes x = 10$ has no solution if $a=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $a \oplus b = \exp(\log(a)+\log(b))$  and  $a \otimes b = \exp(\log(a)\log{(b)})$. So the structure of $\Bbb R$ as a field is ''transportet'' by $\exp$ to $(\Bbb R^+,\oplus,\otimes). $ In other words: Let $f:=\log$, Then
$a\oplus b=f^{-1}(f(a)+f(b))$ and $a\otimes b=f^{-1}(f(a)\cdot f(b))$.

Answer (score 0):

It's isomorphic to $\Bbb R$ with the usual field structure.  The isomorphism is given by $\varphi: \Bbb R^+ \to \Bbb R$ with $\varphi(x)=\log x$.